# Can anyone identify this 1970s Mitsubishi pushback tug?

Tags: aircraft-identification, pushback, japan

What's the original name and specifications of this probably 1970s pushback?  The bottom of this model is stamped "Mitsubishi towing tractor." Made by Tomica. Bought at a flea market in Kyoto circa 2010. Googling finds only the toy.[image: photo of toy]

I'm particularly interested in what looks like an elevating cab, possibly at both ends.

Details from comments so far:  This model is 1:119 scale.  The pushback was in use at Tokyo's Haneda airport at least through 1976-78.  It's *not* a Hough T-500 Paymover.

Photos of other pushbacks show that this one is unusual in having four separate cabs, and wheel arches that are perfectly semicircular.

---

**Sept. 2020 edit** before the bounty expires:
The toy is from a box labeled
ジャンボエアポートセット ミニカー
which translates as Jumbo Airport Set Minicar.  The UPC code is 4904810 26441 5 (or 8 instead of 5).

These sets are sold at the Japanese
[ebay](https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/d455119742).
Can a Japanese speaker glean any clues from the back of the box?  (I can guess at the kana, but not the kanji.)

[image: back of box with Japanese text]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a generic pushback-tug model?

Comment: No.  I have no more data.  But Tomica's reputation for sweating the details is second only to that of [Hergé](http://dardel.info/tintin/indexE.html).  Miyazaki is more obvious, but he produced not nearly as many examples.

Comment: A similar toy with claim that it's a TRACMA: https://1-87vehicles.org/photo242/tracma_tug.php

Comment: @aml "T-500-gvw" Paymover looks close.  https://aviationgse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/HOUGH-T-500-Paymover.pdf

Comment: So is the item you bought, and photographed, the toy or the full-scale item?  (Kidding but also hinting at a possible clarifying edit)

Comment: It's definitely a Mitsubishi, but I don't have any further specs. Yet...

Comment: This one [on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/TOMICA-Mitsubishi-Towing-Tractor-JAL-Japan-Air-Lines-Made-in-Japan-No-95-1-119-/233197937719) is in better condition :-) There is also a [ANA version](https://picclick.com/TOMICA-Mitsubishi-Towing-Tractor-ANA-Air-Lines-Made-273611120407.html)

Comment: [Here it is in use](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Japan-Airlines-JAL/McDonnell-Douglas-DC-10-40D/2253122/L) (1976). [Another one in 1978](https://www.airliners.net/photo/CAAC/Boeing-707-3J6B/2076656/L?qsp=eJwljUsKwzAMRO%2BidTZuoB/v2gs0i15AyCIOpLGRVEgIuXtVdzfMvJnZgcpivNprqwwRlFEoQwcVBd8KcXfgs5hsEE%2Bh7yCh8ZCLlVGwZk7eCbfL1RtaxB6ONeROxNU8/vtPSSy/iJXa%2BOhnwQXL0DT0Z/fTpHXGtsGG0wzH8QUR4DTT)

Comment: Guys ......................... someone POST AN ANSWER to this superb question eh ?!

Comment: Just spent a good while searching photos of airports I have visited. I could swear that I have seen this exact model of tug or one nearly identical to it in the last 2 or 3 years. I remember the tug being very distinctive and interesting due to its configuration. But, I do not remember which airport to which it belonged. I have narrowed it down to Abu Dhabi, Doha, Colombo, or (with a slim chance) Muscat. Wherever it was, it was a fairly long bus ride from the aircraft to the terminal. So we got a fairly good look at the tug. Unfortunately, I can not locate any pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an old magazine advertisement that displays the pushback tractor in question. The ad is for Mitsubishi Heavy Industries "ground support equipment" or G.S.E.:

[image: Mitsubishi G.S.E.]
Source: [Aviationancestry.co.uk](https://www.aviationancestry.co.uk/?searchQuery=Mitsubishi%20heavy&startYear=1909&endYear=1990)

The advertisement is from [Interavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interavia_(magazine)) November 1970 issue (also  March 1971). Unfortunately it offers no further information about the tug, but I will amend this answer if I'm able to dig deeper.

---

AviationAncestry kindly sent a full-resolution version of the image, cropped below.  The four kanji at left also appear on the other 3 vehicles, so they don't identify the pushback itself; they may mean simply Japan Air Lines.  At right, a 10 in a triangle, and either "C 701" or just "701."  Above the front wheel there may be some writing, but it's as small as the grain of the print process.

[image: enlarged photo]

Comment: For a photo with enough resolution to discern text on the pushback, we might need an actual paper copy.  All I can make out here is the JAL logo on the front door.

Comment: This ad *pushes* the pushback's start of operations at Haneda *back* from 1976 to 1970.

Comment: That's the one.  Even the headlights and front fascia match.  Tomica wisely omitted the rear view mirrors, though.  Prepare to be bountified...

Comment: "It has to be towed to the ramp..." Really? The 747 didn't taxi up to the gate under its own power, but was towed in (possibly under early operating procedure)? Or am I misreading that and they're referring to the push-back as "towed to the ramp"? And did they actually wash them between flights as that implies?

Comment: Coincidentally JAL got it's first 747s just in the summer of 1970, so they may have been extra careful with them :)

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune unfortunately my efforts have so far proven fruitless. Japanese companies are proud of their heritage, and often make a plethora of historical material available for the public, but MHI has, quite understandably, decided not to list their entier roster of products on any of their sites...

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I almost got carried away, but unfortunately with some trickery, I found out the kanji reads Japan Airlines: 日本航空, Nihon Kōkū.

Answer (score 6):

- I Have found out this Mitsubishi pushback tug in real life at Haneda airport, Tokyo. but I wasn't able to get the original model number but I belive Mitsubishi hasn't set one for it otherwise the TOMICA toy co. would have named it as the other toys.
- This pushback tug was only associated to pushback the B747 only, since all the photos the tug was with B747 only! cheers

[image: HL-7411 - Boeing 747 235B at Tokyo Haneda Airport in 1974]

[image: China Airlines Boeing 747-132 August 26, 1976]

**References:-**

-https://aflyinghistory.com/search-aeroplane-photographs?query=tokyo+haneda+airport&page=1

-https://www.airliners.net/photo/China-Airlines/Boeing-747-132/2246060

-http://motorcade.weebly.com/mitsubishi.html

Comment: Nice find, the first picture, however, is of a different tug. The wheel arches are not round on that one.

Comment: yeah, I think so but I tried to get all of the pushback tags that were next to a b747 or towing this the ones I found!

Comment: Second photo: so the cabs *do* elevate at both ends!